# Can't check which check list is checked

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete multiple pictures using checkbox item. But somehow pictures are not deleted from database.

the coderuns without mistake. Page is being redirected but the delete query is not executed.

I believe there is somethong to do with passing picture id to query `$List[1]` but i really can't understand what.It seems I'm doing everything ok.

Thanks for any help in advance.

That's the code:

```
<?php
$Connection = mysql_connect( $Host, $User, $Pass ) or die('ERROR: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db( $DataBase )or die('ERROR: '.mysql_error());

$Query = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE folder_id = ".$FolId.";";
$Picture = mysql_query($Query, $Connection)or die('ERROR: '.mysql_error());
?>
    <form name='Photos' method='POST' >
<?php
   while($List = mysql_fetch_array($Picture)){
     echo "<input type='checkbox' name='photoList[]' value='".$List[1]."'> <span> &nbsp;".$List[4]."</span>";
   }
?>
   <input type='submit' name='Delit' value='DELETE'  >
       </form>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['Delit'])){
     foreach($_POST['photoList'] as $item){
       $Query="DELETE FROM pictures WHERE picture_id =".$item;
       mysql_query($Query, $Connection)or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
       header('Location: photos.php');
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: try echoing the query

Comment: mysql extension (mysql_query() etc) is deprecated (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Please use mysqli or pdo (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: I tried. the query works in mysql

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `$List[1]` doesn't contain your `picture_id`.  It's probably `$List[0]`.

Using `fetch_array` is not a great way to get data from a DB using `SELECT *`, as your columns may change position, and an index doesn't clearly say which column you're retrieving.

Try using `fetch_assoc` instead, to get the column names associated with the data.

```
<?php
    // Change `picture_name` below to the name of the column storing your picture's name
    while ($List = mysql_fetch_assoc($Picture)) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='photoList[]' value='{$List['picture_id']}'> <span> &nbsp;{$List['picture_name']}</span>";
    }
?>
```

Also, try this for your `DELETE` logic:

1. Checking if `photoList` is set (vs. `Delit`)
2. Looping through your photo list and casting the values to `(int)` to prevent SQL Injection
3. Concatenating the list of IDs into a comma-delimited list using `implode`
4. Doing a `DELETE... WHERE IN` query, providing the photo ID list - this is much faster than looping through and doing several `DELETE... WHERE =` statements

Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['photoList']) && !empty($_POST['photoList'])) {
        $photoIds = array();
        foreach ($_POST['photoList'] as $photoId) {
            $photoIds[] = (int) $photoId;
        }
        $photoIds = implode(',', $photoIds);
        $Query = "DELETE FROM pictures WHERE picture_id IN ({$photoIds})";
        mysql_query($Query, $Connection)or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
        header('Location: photos.php');
    }
?>
```